# Python Lists extract Elements by identifier

Tags: python, list, iterator, append

I have two list in Python and want to exctract values them by theier first column. The first list has two columns and the second has one coulmn:

```
 type:  id:
 xc1x   45
 xf4g   65
 gthz   32
 gtr7   22

 type:  (new ID)
 xc1x
 xc1x
 gtr7
 xf4g
 xc1x
 gthz
 gtr7
```

The second list should append the IDs from the first list by the Type. So Python should iterate through the second list(just "type") and grab the IDs from the first list(type and id) when there is a match. What is a good way to do this? The list have 50-1000 rows.

Comment: How does a list have a "column"?  Is the first list a list of tuples?

Comment: I used the "list(zip(ab,cb))" function to put two lists togther and create the first list

Comment: That does indeed make a list of tuples.  Is there a reason you're doing it that way instead of making a dictionary?

Comment: The zip() function i use for many other lists containing more than two values. Mostly its three to seven values put together. In this case a dictionary is a good idea. But as i know a dict is only for two values and not more.

Answer (score 0):

How is this lists are stored? Seems like a dictionary. If that's the case, you just need to iterate the first and store its value in the second. That's seems like you are looking how to Join.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, the first list is created as a list of tuples by doing `list(zip(ab, cb))`.  I think you'd be better off creating this as a dict instead:

```
id_dict = {type: id for type, id in zip(ab, cb)}  # this is the "first list" equivalent
```

Now to get the ID for anything in the second list you can just do:

```
for type in second_list:
    id = id_dict[type]  # now do whatever you want with this
```

or you can use another comprehension to build another dict or list.  Having more context on the ultimate goal would make it easier to suggest what direction to take this in from here.